# How to pickle a function

Tags: python, pickle

I know that I can define a function in a Python script and then `pickle` it. I also know that I can't pickle `lambda` expressions. Let's say that I defined a function `functionA(x, y = 2)` and now I would like to create another function (not by defining it using `def` keyword) `functionB` which is a `functionA` but with argument `y = 3`. I can write

`functionB = lambda x: functionA(x, y = 3)`

but in that case I can't pickle it. How can I pickle it but without defining a function:

```
def functionB(x, y = 3):
    return functionA(x, y = y)
```

Comment: why is `def`'ing a second function off the table?

Comment: Why do you even want to pickle a function?

Comment: As an aside, the `lambda` that you propose doesn't actually change the default value; it *sets* a value for that parameter. It is not allowed to override the `y = 3` setting that way.